# The PDE $u_t = u_{xx}$ follows the path defined by $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \pm \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, heat-equation, characteristics

I have the PDE $u_t = u_{xx}$ (heat equation).

I am then told that, by writing the equation as $(\partial_x + (0)\partial_t)^2 u = u_t$, we see that its characteristics would follow the path defined by $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \pm \infty$.

I wonder how they came to this conclusion? Please kindly explain. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a second order PDE in two variables $x$ and $t$,
$$
a(x,t) u_{xx} + 2b(x,t) u_{xt} + c(x,t) u_{tt} + \dots = 0
,
$$
there is an associated quadratic form at each point $(x,t)$,
$$
Q(h,k) = a(x,t) h^2 + 2b(x,t) hk + c(x,t) k^2
,
$$
and a characteristic curve is a curve whose normal vector $(h,k)$ satisfies $Q(h,k)=0$ at each point of the curve.

For the heat equation we have simply
$$
Q(h,k)=h^2
$$
so the normal vector should be $(h,k)=(0,1)$ at each point, which forces the characteristics to be lines of constant $t$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm struggling to see how this relates to my question? It says that by writing the equation as $(\partial_x + (0)\partial_t)^2 u = u_t$, we see that its characteristics would follow the path defined by $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \pm \infty$? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say what you are expected to know, since you haven't told us the source of the statement, but presumably they are referring to some earlier explanation of how to read off the characteristics from a factorisation. At least if you have constant coefficients, factoring the differential operator is the same as factoring the quadratic form. In this case, it's just $h^2 = (1h+0k)^2$, which makes it easy to see for which vectors the quadratic form is zero. And this tells you the slope of the characteristic, in this case “1/0”.

Comment: But where did you get $1/0$ from?

Comment: From $1h+0k$, the coefficients are $1$ and $0$. So the vector $(h,k)=(-0,1)$ (swap the numbers and change one sign) will make the quadratic form zero. So this is the normal vector of the characteristic. Thus the vector $(1,0)$ (swap back and change one sign) is a tangent vector of the characteristic. So the slope is $1/0$ or $0/1$ depending on whether you write $dx/dt$ or $dt/dx$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately the textbook does not provide any information beyond what I gave in the main post which is why I had so much trouble understanding it in the first place. But thanks to you and Joonas Ilmavirta, I understand now

Answer (score 3):

The rewriting of the PDE collects the leading order (second order) derivatives on the right-hand side, as the characteristics should be determined by the leading order terms.
If you have a vector $v=(a,b)$ in the $(x,t)$-plane, then the characteristics of the second order operator $(v\cdot\nabla)^2=(a\partial_x+b\partial_t)^2$ are lines in the direction of the vector $v$.
In this particular case $a=1$ and $b=0$, so the line points in the $x$ direction with no $t$ component.
This conclusion is then expressed — in my opinion clumsily — by saying that $\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm\infty$.

Since you gave no source in your question, I can't interpret everything.
But there is truth to the statement: the heat equation (not only in $1+1$ dimensions) has infinite speed of propagation, meaning that solutions travel infinitely fast in all directions.
This is described in the question as $\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm\infty$, but I do hope the source you are using also gives a description in words.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately the textbook does not provide any information beyond what I gave in the main post which is why I had so much trouble understanding it in the first place. But thanks to you and Hans Lundmark, I understand now